# Setting default option and disabling alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, squarespace

I've been trying for some time now to get this to work. I don't have much experience with jquery or javascript. I want to set a default option that is selected from the drop down options when the button is pressed. I hope this will also prevent the alert(not sure if that's correct) from appearing. I have add the following code to the "code injection" part of squarespace, which seems to work fine. (Edited, I have removed the code as recommend)

I'm using the Brine template. Here's a link to the website https://www.metastudio35.com/private-photography-services/event-collection the password is "Google360".

```
<squarespace:script src="plugin.js" combo="true"?>
<squarespace:script src="site.js" combo="true"?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I then added the code below in the page I needed to redirect the button. Which also works, but without the "$("#Additional Photos").val("0");" and  "$( ".sqs-widgets-confirmation-content clear" ).dialog( "close" )" lines.

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){


     $("#Additional Photos").val("0");

     $( ".sqs-widgets-confirmation-content clear" ).dialog( "close" )

    $(".sqs-add-to-cart-button").click(function(){
      window.location = '/booking/';

  });
   });


 </script>
```

This is a screenshot of the dialog box I want to remove/disable.
[dialog box pop up screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YttYb.png)

If someone could point me in the right direction or tell me what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly apprenticed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi there. With questions like this for Squarespace, it's easiest to provide a quality answer if you can provide A) what template you're using B) a link to the site/page in question and C) the view-only password if applicable (for sites in trial-mode). If you can do that, it's likely an working answer can be provided. You may also consider removing your own code so that it does not conflict with others' testing.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will add the extra information and remove the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your website and it seems like jQuery is not used by your template, and instead of including jQuery just for this simple function, I've written the below code in vanilla JS instead.

```
function setValue() {

    var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('[data-variant-option-name="Additional Photos"]')[0];
    dropdown.value = '0';
    Y.one('#'+dropdown.id).simulate('change');

}

window.onload = setValue;
```

---

If you're interested in figuring out why your code wasn't working, here's the explanation :

```
$('#Additional Photos').val("0")
```

This line of code is setting the element **that has** an **ID** of "Additional Photos" with a value of "0".

Your "Additional Photos" select box **does not** have an **ID** of "Additional Photos", instead - it has a **randomly generated ID** that re-generates each time the page is refreshed.

So the reason that your code isn't working is because you're simply targeting the wrong element :)

---

```
var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('[data-variant-option-name="Additional Photos"]')[0];
```

Due to the fact that the ID of the select  box is not constant, we are targeting the select box by the 'data-variant-option-name' attribute instead. I figured out this constant  attribute simply by inspecting the selectbox on the ChromDev tools.

---

```
dropdown.value = '0';
Y.one('#'+dropdown.id).simulate('change');
```

The other thing to consider is the fact that your template is using **YUI** to handle the select box. This means that we need to manually trigger the 'change' event in order for the UI to update. As you can see from the code above, the first line is setting the value of the select box, while the second is telling YUI to simulate the 'change' event, and thus - updating the UI.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly. Thank you for also explaining what I was doing wrong. This was a huge help.